# Maintain a sidebar with links, without having to change the html of each individual page

Tags: sharepoint-designer, html

I want to add a sidebar with links to some of my pages.

[image]

But I don't want to go to each page an manually update each one.

[image]

I've looked into having a php include() statement that takes html from one document and puts it in the sidebar, but it looks like that wouldn't work.

I feel like there should be an easy way to have one html document to change instead of every link.

Thanks!

Comment: SharePoint comes with an OOT side navigation panel. Why don't you just add your links to that? Other option is to go to your root site and create/edit a master page and add your links to it.

Comment: Try looking into the Reusable HTML list in the root of your site collection, https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-reusable-content-867896D1-D2A9-41A0-8EC1-45EA17DA3DD2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative to the OOT side panel (which I don't have control over), I ended up using the content manager and an HTML document.

It's a bit of a pain to add the content manager to every page, but once it's done, I can just update the link bar by editing the one HTML document. I also have the benefit of being able to use Jquery to customize the page (I used it to make the preset sidepanel smaller)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Good job Eric . but I think it is not a best practice why you didn't update your page layout to applied for all pages that use this page layout !

Comment: I have no idea how to do that. I am new to sharepoint, and didn't setup anything myself. I was given a few pages to maintain, is this easy? Do I need special privileges? 

I poked around for a long time and never saw anything about page layouts.

But I would love to do it the right/best way :)